# How can I redirect netbios requests?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-server-2016, file-server, netbios

I've got a fileserver which we've had to decommision... Lets call it FILE-OLD.

It's been replaced by a shiny new fileserver, lets call that one FILE-NEW.

FILE-NEW has the same IP as FILE-OLD used to have, and pinging FILE-OLD gets a reply due to a DNS CNAME I've put in place.

The shares are passed as mapped drives to the session host server, and theyre not working.  :(
If I browse to \FILE-NEW I can see all of the shares, but browsing to \FILE-OLD I am met with an error 'FILE-OLD is not accessible'.

Is there a way in which I can make FILE-NEW respond to the requests for FILE-OLD?

I know that if I had group policy shares and DFS etc this would be easy, but I'm not blessed with that luxury - Its a soltion I inherited and I really dont want to manually update 100+ users mapped drives. :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to disable strict name checking. - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3181029/smb-file-server-share-access-is-unsuccessful-through-dns-cname-alias

Comment: do i do this on the session host servers which are trying to access the shares?

Comment: You do this on the new file server.

Comment: Ok, done that and rebooted - no change :(

Comment: See if this resolves it - https://argonsys.com/learn-microsoft-cloud/library/using-computer-name-aliases-in-place-of-dns-cname-records/

Comment: You can also add alternate names to your server. This would be my choice. But there are other solutions as well: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/josebda/2010/06/04/multiple-names-for-one-computer-consolidate-your-smb-file-servers-without-breaking-unc-paths/

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way in which I can make FILE-NEW respond to the requests for FILE-OLD?

If the machine FILE-OLD has been turned off (and removed from the domain), you cann add an alternative alias to the new servers (real) name.

This is done in the domain, which wil take care of the rest, like SPNs, DNS records and double-nameed-sessions.

`C:\> netdom computername FILE-NEW /add:FILE-OLD`

- Check your domains local zone after the reboot of the server; I've seen missing A records sometimes.
- Add the name exacactly as you are going to use it (FQDN recommended)